# Using dplyr n_distinct in function with quoted variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr within a function, passing in a column name as a variable to then be used with n_distinct in the summarize function.

I understand that programming with dplyr has become easier, with the summarize_, arrange_ etc functions, as described in vignette(nse).  I've tried various combinations of interp from lazyeval as well.  n_distinct responses with "Input to n_distinct() must be a single variable name from the data set" (which makes sense, it's just that I have the variable name in a string ...)

This works fine outside a function (mention is a column name in the data.frame):

```
summarize(data, count=n_distinct(mention))
```

This was my first effort:

```
getProportions <- function(datain, id_column) {
    overall_total <- summarize(datain, count=n_distinct(id_column))[1,1]
}

getProportions(measures, "mention")
```

And after reading the NSE documentation and some threads on here about programming with dplyr I tried:

```
overall_total <- summarize_(datain, count=interp(~n_distinct(var),var=as.name(id_column)))[1,1]
```

but to no avail.  Any ideas? Almost seems like n_distinct_() is needed?

**Edit**
My apologies and thanks.  You are right, the interp version does work, it seems that I never quite hit that full combination. I looked over my old versions and when I have the var part right I was using plain summarize() and when I used summarize_() I left off the var= part of the interp call.  Sigh. My fault for not producing a full working example with both versions.

Comment: Not sure there the problem is since this works for me: `f <- function(data, col) summarise_(data, count = interp(~n_distinct(var), var = as.name(col)))` and then `f(mtcars, "cyl")` returns the correct output. Can you clarify what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks again (I edited the answer). This was a non-question; should I delete it?

Comment: You can delete it or answer it yourself and accept it since others might find it useful in the future

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the comments, the right way to do this was my second option, which apparently I had never quite tested (i'd left of the var = part of the interp call.):

```
f <- function(data, col) {
        summarise_(data, count = interp(~n_distinct(var), var = as.name(col)))
}
f(mtcars, "cyl")
```

Comment: I needed to qualify the namespace of the interp function to get this to work i.e. lazyeval::interp

Comment: Indeed, worked for me too. But I found that `length(unique(col))` is WAY faster than `n_distinct(col)` in any dplyr calculation. No idea why.